# Webpack 3 and importing fonts in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I'm building a webpack app using Backbone and attempting to import my CSS with a line like

```
import './css/style.css';
```

However my CSS file uses a True Type font.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Scramble";
  src: url(./scramble/Scramble.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

How can I tell webpack where to find the font?  Do I need another loader?

Currently I get:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './scramble/Scramble.ttf'
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpack needs to know how to load that kind of asset. `npm install url-loader` and add the below rule to your webpack configuration which resolves common font file extensions.

```
rules : [
  {
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          mimetype: 'application/octet-stream'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
 // more rules
]
```